# How to override the color of a react-bootstrap button (bsStyle)?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-bootstrap

Is it possible to override the default color for the 'success' button in react-bootstrap?

My code: `<Label bsStyle='success'>{myNumber}</Label>`

The default for the success button is `#5cb85c`

I would like the button to be a slightly different green (`#70bf41`) to match the rest of my application.

Comment: If you want to override the bootstrap colors throughout your application, then I'd recommend loading in the bootstrap styles as SCSS so that you can [change the variables](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap-sass#usage) for every component before compiling to CSS.

Answer (score 1):

As of this date, I accomplished this by copying the styles for `btn-success` from [the CDN](https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css) into my App.css and renamed them to `btn-optin` and made my changes.

```
.btn-optin {
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #712687;
    border-color: #9409b5;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

.btn-optin.focus, .btn-optin:focus {
    color: #fff;
    filter:brightness(70%);
}

.btn-optin:hover {
    color: #fff;
    filter:brightness(85%);
}

.btn-optin.active, .btn-optin:active, .open > .dropdown-toggle.btn-optin {
    color: #fff;
    filter:brightness(70%);
}

.btn-optin.active.focus, .btn-optin.active:focus, .btn-optin.active:hover, .btn-optin:active.focus, .btn-optin:active:focus, .btn-optin:active:hover, .open > .dropdown-toggle.btn-optin.focus, .open > .dropdown-toggle.btn-optin:focus, .open > .dropdown-toggle.btn-optin:hover {
    color: #fff;
    filter:brightness(70%);
}

.btn-optin.active, .btn-optin:active, .open > .dropdown-toggle.btn-optin {
    color: #fff;
    background-image: none;
}

.btn-optin.disabled.focus, .btn-optin.disabled:focus, .btn-optin.disabled:hover, .btn-optin[disabled].focus, .btn-optin[disabled]:focus, .btn-optin[disabled]:hover, fieldset[disabled] .btn-optin.focus, fieldset[disabled] .btn-optin:focus, fieldset[disabled] .btn-optin:hover {
    color: #fff;
}

.btn-optin .badge {
    color: #fff;
}
```

In my component I imported the `utils` and added my new style for `<Button>` to avoid a nastygram in the Console output.

```
import { utils } from 'react-bootstrap';
utils.bootstrapUtils.addStyle(Button, "optin");
```

`It works for me`™ but YMMV.

Answer (score 0):

`bsClass` props is supported by `<Label/>`. -> [doc](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components.html#label-props)

So you can pass a custom css class and the class style use color you want.

I use a pseudo code to present my meaning.

```
<style>
  .custom-color {
    color: #70bf41;
  }
</style>

// react component
<Label bsClass="custom-color">{myNumber}</Label>
```

Comment: This changes the actual `.label` class, which would remove the regular label styles. If you need to extend the Label styles with a custom color, the `className` prop is passed through to the `span` element.